# How to render tree

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a grid and I would like to add a tree if a name is equal to “Beto Carlx” Does anyone know how to make this happen? Thank you in advance!

Here’s my code: [**LIVE DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/henryDev/5bdv1ycj/7/)

```
columns: [{
    header: 'NAME',
    renderer: function(val, metadata, record) {
        var recordName = record.get('name');
        if (recordName === "Beto carlx") {
            return "TEST";
        }

        return recordName;
    },
    dataIndex: 'name',
    }],
```

**I'm trying to use this simple tree:**

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
root: {
    expanded: true,
    children: [
        { text: "Beto carlx", expanded: true, children: [
            { text: "item 1", leaf: true },
            { text: "item 2", leaf: true}
        ] }
    ]
}
});

Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
  width: 200,
  height: 150,
  store: store,
  rootVisible: false,
  renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "add a simple tree"? You mean you want to render a tree inside the grid cell?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli yes render a tree inside a grid cell. Any ideas how to make that happen? Thanks

Comment: Not in those versions without creating a memory leak. In the 6.x line there's a row widget and column widget which will render a component in a grid in such a fashion.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli yeah I'm not using version6.x

Comment: how about creating a combobox with a custom tree picker (using the createPicker fn to return a tree panel) and then using the cell editing plugin to show that custom component in the cell?

Comment: Have you checked this?  4.1 - http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/example/tree/reorder.html and 5 -https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/lb5&view/editor

Comment: You can render a Component with "if logic" in your grid,http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/guides/components/widgets_widgets_columns.html, and tree looks like, http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/guides/components/trees.html#components-_-trees_-_loading_the_entire_tree , remove what you do not need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can be achieve this functionality by `html` tag inside of [`renderer`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-renderer) of [`gridcolumn`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column).

I this **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2fsr)**, I have created a demo using `html` tag inside of `renderer` config. Hope this will help you to achieve your requirement.

---

***Update***

You can use [`cellclick`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.panel.Table-event-cellclick) to put `collapseexpand` function inside of ExtJS component or controller.

For design pas I have worked for that not fully same. I have used [font-awesome](https://fontawesome.com/icons) for icons and put css for dashed border.

---

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {

        Ext.define('UserModal', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
            fields: ['name']
        });

        Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            storeId: 'gridStore',

            fields: ['name'],
            groupField: 'status',
            data: [{
                "name": "Henry Watson"
            }, {
                "name": "Lucy"
            }, {
                "name": "Mike Brow"
            }, {
                "name": "Mary Tempa"
            }, {
                "name": "Beto Carlx"
            }]
        });

        // Setting up the Grid
        Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {

            title: 'Render Treen inside grid cell',

            store: 'gridStore',

            columns: [{
                header: 'NAME',
                renderer: function (val, metadata, record) {
                    if (val === "Beto Carlx") {
                        return `<ul  class="root-tree">
                            <li><i class="fa fa-minus-square"></i> <span>Beto carlx</span>
                                <ul class="tree-item">
                                  <li class="tree-item-li">item 1</li>
                                  <li class="tree-item-li">item 1</li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>`
                    }

                    return val;
                },
                dataIndex: 'name',

            }],
            listeners: {
                cellclick: function (grid, td, cellIndex, record, tr, rowIndex, e) {
                    var list,
                        styles;

                    if (e.getTarget('ul.root-tree', 3)) {
                        list = td.querySelector('ul.tree-item');
                        var icon = td.querySelector('i.fa').classList;
                        if (icon.contains('fa-minus-square')) {
                            icon.remove('fa-minus-square');
                            icon.add('fa-plus-square');
                            list.style.display = 'none';
                        } else {
                            icon.remove('fa-plus-square');
                            icon.add('fa-minus-square');
                            list.style.display = 'block';
                        }
                        // styles = window.getComputedStyle(list);
                        //  = (styles.getPropertyValue('display') === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none');
                    } else if (e.target.className == 'tree-item-li') {
                        alert(e.getTarget('li.tree-item-li').innerText)
                    }
                }
            },

            height: 300,

            renderTo: document.body
        });

    }
});
```

> CSS part

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
    .root-tree {
        cursor: pointer;
        color: #5c5c5c;
        font-weight:bold;
    }

    .root-tree span:hover {
        color: green;
    }

    ul.tree-item,
    ul.tree-item ul {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0px 10px;
        padding: 0;
    }

    ul.tree-item ul {
        margin-left: 10px;
    }

    ul.tree-item li {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0 7px;
        line-height: 20px;
        color: #5c5c5c;
        font-weight: bold;
        border-left: 1px dashed rgb(100, 100, 100)
    }

    ul.tree-item li:last-child {
        border-left: none;
    }

    ul.tree-item li:before {
        position: relative;
        top: -0.3em;
        height: 1em;
        width: 12px;
        color: white;
        border-bottom: 1px dashed rgb(100, 100, 100);
        content: "";
        display: inline-block;
        left: -7px;
    }

    ul.tree-item li:last-child:before {
        border-left: 1px dashed rgb(100, 100, 100)
    }

</style>
```

> *Note I have implemented only for **Beto Carlx** with static html. You can put your logic with dynamic inside of renderer function.

Comment: Can you put your function collapseexpand inside app.js? I'm having issues calling it from another file. Also, how would add the tree icons to Beto Carlx and its sub elements? (icons like the ones I have in my image)

Comment: @HenryDev I have updated my answer and [FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2fsr).

Comment: @HenryDev I have updated code and  **[FIDDLE.](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2fsr)**

Answer (score 1):

I have a partial solution, the only problem is that extjs doesn't like nested grids ou treepanels. The events overlap and it gives some console erros like : "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isGroupHeader' of null".

Here is the [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/725a0cfL/1/)

```
      var CreateTree = function(){

          var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
             root: {
             expanded: true,
             children: [
              { text: "Beto carlx", expanded: true, children: [
                  { text: "item 1", leaf: true },
                  { text: "item 2", leaf: true}
               ] }
             ]
           }
         });

         var tree = Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
            width: 200,     
            store: store,
            rootVisible: false     
         });     
         tree.render('myDiv');       

    }

    renderer: function (val, metadata, record) {

            var recordName = record.get('name');

            if (recordName === "Beto Carlx") {
                setTimeout(CreateTree, 300);                 
                return "<span id=myDiv ></span>"; 
            }                

            return recordName;
     }
```

"If it works, its not stupid!"